# Log all events in wxWidgets in the whole application?

Tags: wxwidgets

I have a large application, with many dynamic parts/panels/widgets. Upon stress-testing, The GUI goes blank. I doubt that the GUI thread is bombarded with events from other threads.

I have disabled all the events that I doubted, but it still goes blank. So is there like a global handler or logger to log all the events that occur in the wxWidgets main loop ?

N.B: I have around 1000 threads.

Comment: how many windows/controls do you have at any given time? Are you accessing the thread directly from the GUI Or you sending the event? Do you create many custom pen/brushes/etc (basically GDI objects)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your application class override [FilterEvent](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_app_console.html#ada7ab606e014a10d46e4b3c6f602e20c). You can do whatever logging you need in your derived method, but be sure to return -1 to allow the events to be processed as they normally would.